# How to get Chat Dialog By Id in QuickBlox municate android?

Tags: android, quickblox

i try to get Chat Dialog By Id at this code:

```
`  QBRestChatService.getChatDialogById("59aefb2ca0eb475750844ae8").performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<QBChatDialog>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QBChatDialog qbChatDialog, Bundle bundle) {
            AppLog.Log(TAG, "getChatDialogById NAME=" + qbChatDialog.getName() + " QBChatDialog TYPE= " + qbChatDialog.getType());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
            AppLog.Log(TAG, "getChatDialogById QBResponseException onError " + e.getMessage());

        }
    });`
```

but i got this Exception :

> QBResponseException onError Entity you are looking for was not found.

Why?

- **59aefb2ca0eb475750844ae8** is an existing group ID. I'm not a member of it.
- Room jid = 61447_59aefb2ca0eb475750844ae8@muc.chat.quickblox.com
- Room Type = Group

Answer (score 0):

this is expected result, QuickBlox server returns only dialogs in which you is a member or Public group. You can't add himself to Group dialog.